# access current selected element with in the options

Tags: jquery, plugins, selector, this

i have wrote a simple popup plugin that simple pops up a div and black out screen. it works in two way. simple message and loading with ajax. here is my problem

i have list of polls like this :

```
<div id="pollList" style=" margin-top:10px;">
<li pollId='1'><strong>polling number 1</strong></a><br /><span style='font-size:9px;'>this is a test polling</span></li>
<li pollId='2'><strong>polling number 2</strong></a><br /><span style='font-size:9px;'>this is a test polling</span></li>
```

now i want that my plugin apply to all this li tags, so i have used this :

```
$("#pollList li").popup({
    width:800,
    height:400,
    popupType:'ajax',
    ajaxURL:root+'polls/attend/poll/'+$(this).attr('pollId')
 });
```

here is the problem i want to pass the $(this).attr('pollId') into the plugin to call the related URL but $(this) seems to not work and return 'undefined' how could i access pollId attribute whit in the plugin options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` you have is probably the global object or if you're in an event handler the object for which the handler was bound. Anyway to get the proper context you can use the each function to set the url according to the specific `li`.

```
$("#pollList li").each(function(){
  $(this).popup({
    width:800,
    height:400,
    popupType:'ajax',
    ajaxURL:root+'polls/attend/poll/'+$(this).attr('pollId')
  }); 
});
```

Also you might want to use data attributes rather than arbitrary one.